# Why am I not able to append an image only if certain classes exist?

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to use jQuery to append an image tag to a div only if one of three classes exists, but it doesn't seem to be working. It either appends to all of the elements or none at all.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<figure class="donut minus">
    <div class="figure-value"></div>
</figure>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
if ($("figure.donut").hasClass("minus") || $("figure.donut").hasClass("plus") || $("figure.donut").hasClass("plus-minus")) {
        $(".figure-value").append('<img src="../images/schoolProfile/donut-plus-minus.png" />');
    }
```

Comment: I dont see a problem in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/STYap/

Comment: Not really, Dom. You need to try a few extra figures: http://jsfiddle.net/Csvxf/1/  You'll see that it adds the image to all, because the appended image isn't actually targeting *this* selected/if element, but, rather, all  $(".figure-value").

Comment: @karthikr The problem is that the original code will append the `img` to every `.figure-value` element, not just the ones matching the classes the OP wants...

Comment: The code in this question will append an image to all donuts if *any* have the required classes.  It actually says, directly translated: "if any `figure.donut` has the `minus` class, or any `figure.donut` has the `plus` class, or any `figure.donut` has the `plus-minus` class, then append an image to all `.figure-value`s".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of an if try using filter:

```
$("figure.donut")
    .filter(".plus, .minus, .plus-minus")
    .find(".figure-value")
    .append('<img src="../images/schoolProfile/donut-plus-minus.png" />');
```

This will find all of the figures with a class of donut and plus, minus or plus-minus and then find the element with a class of figure-value inside them and append the image.

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/7FUam/

In answer to the comment below, change the append to create a jQuery object and apply the css to that:

```
.append($('<img src="../images/schoolProfile/donut-plus-minus.png" />')
            .css({"top": -100+"px", "left": 0+"px"}));
```

Update Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/7FUam/1/

Comment: Very nice! Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up, how could I add positioning to the appended img? I tried adding .css({"top": -100+"px", "left": 0+"px"}); after the .append, but that didn't seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: @PaulLemky Please see my edit for how to apply css to the newly created element

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your code:

```
$(".figure-value").append('<img src="../images/schoolProfile/donut-plus-minus.png" />');
```

You are selecting ALL elements with a class of `.figure-value` and appending the image.

The solution would be to use `$.each` as such (`$.each` allows you to iterate over a collection of element(s) and perform operation(s):

```
$('figure').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('plus') ) {
        $(this).find('.figure-value')
        .append('<img src="http://placehold.it/125x125" />');   
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mV56V/1/

This example will take each `figure` element and check if it has a class of `.plus` - if the element has a `.plus` class there will be an image inserted inside it's relative `.figure-value` element.

Comment: Wholly unnecessary use of `.each`.  `if ($(this).hasClass('x')) { ... }` is much more appropriately done as `.filter('.x')`, and the rest is designed to work with lists of elements.